# How to prove a given sequence of x86 instructions is shortest possible?

Tags: cpu

Say we want to find a shortest possible sequence of x86 instructions to move the $9^{th} - 16^{th}$ bit of the $eax$ register to the $24^{th} - 31^{th}$ bit of the $ebx$ register without changing the other bits of the $ebx$ register, where the least significant bit is defined to be the $0^{th}$ bit.

An obvious solution is:

```
ror eax, 1
rol ebx, 8
mov bl, ah
ror ebx, 8
```

But how do I prove this is the shortest possible? Is there a nice way to do it? If not, is there a nice piece of FOSS software to brute force it?

Comment: If we're talking problems as easy and programs as small as this, just enumerate *all* shorter programs and check if the solve the problem. In general, the problem is, of course, not computable.

Comment: Seems like you'd always have to start from a brute-force search, then use any trick you happen to know to optimize the search process.  Exactly what "optimizing the search process" means is really implementation-subjective.

Comment: How interested are you in this problem?  For example, was it a random thought that you wanted to explore, or is it a problem that you're seeking a good general solution for as part of, say, an optimizing compiler?

Comment: @Nat It is more like something to explore.